# parsing hstore in python3 using sqlalchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, hstore

I have a csv file where one of the columns is written in hstore format. I would like to convert it into python dict but at the same time keep my code DRY. My codebase uses sqlalchemy, which has a `_parse_hstore` function defined in https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/master/lib/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/hstore.py#L390. I tried to import it like this:

```
import sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.hstore as hstore
```

But unfortunately the upstream module (`sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql`) shadows the hstore module with an object: [https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/master/lib/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/**init**.py#L53](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/master/lib/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/__init__.py#L53)

Is it still possible to import the module somehow? I'd prefer not to copy function code directly into my codebase even if the function is relatively simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use function `HSTORE.result_processor` (`from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import HSTORE`) which is wrapper for private `_parse_hstore` function.

```
>>> h = sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.HSTORE()
>>> f = h.result_processor(None, None)
>>> f('"a"=>"1"')
{'a': '1'}
```

Snippet credits to [@lbolla](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1063605/lbolla).